# JS if statement not working properly

Tags: javascript, variables

I am working on this script, and for some reason, it is acting as if fn.style.borderColor always equals #F00. All I want is for the second one to execute if and only if the first if has been executed.

```
function vfn() {
   if (fnl<1){
      na.innerHTML= "This field is required.";
      fn.style.borderColor="#F00";
   } 
   else if (fn.style.borderColor="#F00" && fnl>1) {
      if(lnl>1){
         na.innerHTML= "OK";
         setTimeout("na.innerHTML = ''",1500)
      }
      fn.style.borderColor="#0F0";
      setTimeout("fn.style.borderColor='';",1500)
   }
   return false
}
```

I tried using variables and did something like this, but it didn't work at all.

```
var error = 1
if (error = 1) {
    alert("error1");
    var error = 2
}
else if (error == "2") {
    alert("error2")
    var error = 1
}
```

So how can I make this work?

------------------------------------->>EDIT<<------------------------------------

Ok, so I changed it to this

```
  function vfn() {
      if (fnl<1){
        na.innerHTML= "This field is required.";
        fn.style.borderColor="#F00";
        }
      else if (fn.style.borderColor == "#F00" && fnl>1){
        if(lnl>1){
            na.innerHTML= "OK";
            setTimeout("na.innerHTML = ''",1500)}
        fn.style.borderColor="#0F0";
        setTimeout("fn.style.borderColor='';",1500)
        }

        return false}
```

and what's happening is that the border color is changed to red when the field is empty, which is what should happen, But when the field is filled in properly, it is SUPPOSED to change to green, then after 1.5 seconds, change back to default, but instead, what actually happens is that it stays red, as if it is ignoring the else if block of code, even though the field is already red (the fn.style.borderColor="#F00").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make your else if look like this:

`else if (fn.style.borderColor == "rgb(255, 0, 0)" && fnl>1){`

Comment: Strange though, why is it that it wants the rbd instead of hexadecimal?

Comment: @Sean: The browser may convert your `#F00` to a different representation when you store it -- Firefox chooses `rgb` for example, but it's not safe to rely on any such value. It's best that you store the red/green state in your own variable.

Answer (score 6):

Common mistake/typo: you're using `=` (assignment) instead of `==` (comparison). Change:

```
else if (fn.style.borderColor="#F00"
```

to

```
else if (fn.style.borderColor=="#F00"
```

---

**Update:** I would suggest trying your previous approach of using an extra variable, although you may have had a similar error there that caused it not to work before. Try storing a flag that indicates the state instead of explicitly comparing the `borderColor`, because the browser may change its internal representation from `#F00` to something else:

```
var isRed = false;
function vfn() {
   if (fnl<1){
      na.innerHTML= "This field is required.";
      fn.style.borderColor="#F00";
      isRed = true;
   } 
   else if (isRed && fnl>1) {
      if(lnl>1){
         na.innerHTML= "OK";
         setTimeout("na.innerHTML = ''",1500)
      }
      fn.style.borderColor="#0F0";
      isRed = false;
      setTimeout("fn.style.borderColor='';",1500)
   }
  return false
}
```

Comment: Ah, one of those fun places we've *all* been, at least a thousand times... =)

Comment: Even better, use `===` rather than `==`.

Comment: The second example contains the same issue:  `if(error=1)` should be `if(error == 1)`.  Also, it declares the variable `error` multiple times.  The first `var error` is correct, the other two should omit the `var` (eg: `error=2;` *not* `var error=2`)

Comment: @Matt Ball: +1 but `===` can bite just like `=` if used in the wrong places, especially with host objects that can be `toString`-ed but aren't really strings. :)

Comment: @Lee: Right, `error=1` is a problem once again, but redeclaring a variable does no harm.

Comment: Hmm... still not working. when I use the ==, then the else if does not execute. Same with ===

Comment: @Sean: Maybe you should edit your question to explain what end result you're expecting, and we can help you frame the logic for that.

Comment: @casablanca: *in this context* redeclaring the variable does no harm - that's true.  But it is a *really bad* thing to get in the habit of doing, because redeclaring a variable within the scope of a function causes it to be *a new* variable that shadows the variable of same name from the outer scope -- many hard to find errors have come from this "harmless" bad habit.